# How to parse XML tag by Javax.xml library

Tags: java, xml, parsing, tags

I'm trying to parse a simple XML file, like this:

```
<customer id="100">
    <age value=" 29"/>
    <name value="Bob"/>
</customer>
```

I used the library of JAX in this way:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Customer {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "id")
    String id;
    @XmlAttribute(name = "value")
    String value;
    String name;
    String age;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "value")
    public void setAge(String age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "id")
    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

There is an IllegalAnnotationExceptions.
I was expired by this link: [here](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/solutions/jpatoxml003.htm) but without success.

Comment: `age` and `name` are not attributes in your XML. They are child nodes. If your XML was something like `<customer id="100" age="29" name="Bob">...` it would be different. Then `age` and `name` would be direct attributes of your `customer` node.

Comment: My XML file can't change, sorry for that. The example is extracted from here: https://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/ but reporting the xml at my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "name" and "age" values are in fact attributes of child nodes, you should extract it into separate class, kinda:

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public static class Customer {

    @XmlAttribute
    String id;

    @XmlElement
    NameAgeValue name;

    @XmlElement
    NameAgeValue age;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getAge() {
        return (age == null) ? null : age.value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return (name == null) ? null : name.value;
    }
}

@XmlType
public static class NameAgeValue {

    @XmlAttribute
    String value;
}
```

Comment: By your way I have only id=100, but name and age are empty(" ")

Comment: I did tested my code over your XML example. `getAge` and `getName` of parsed object return expected result.

Comment: careful NameAgeValue class should be into the main brackets of the Customer class and Customer class no static ;)

Comment: @OutOfMemoryError this is a snippet from a test class, thus `Customer` is static inner as well